# Initialise vector elements without calling initialization function

Tags: c++, enums, initialization

I have: `enum ID` and `std::vector<BlockData> DATA`

Enum to abstract away indexes.
And DATA containing info for each index.

It should be possible to do something like: DATA[ID::AIR]

Each `DATA` element is constant, and known at compile time

```
class BlockData {
public:
    int someData;
    BlockData() = default;
    explicit BlockData(int someData) : someData(someData) {};
};

namespace Blocks {
    enum ID {
        AIR = 0,
        DIRT = 1,
    };
    std::vector<BlockData> DATA(2);

    void init() {
        Blocks::DATA[Blocks::ID::AIR] = BlockData{32};
        Blocks::DATA[Blocks::ID::DIRT] = BlockData{6};
    }
}
```

I could just initialise `DATA` vector inline, like:
`std::vector<BlockData> DATA(block1data, block2data);`

But i want to assign them using enum, for more readability, like i did in code. The problem is that it requires some initialization function. Is it possible to do that without calling initialization function? And ideally without littering namespace with functions and other data related to initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an inline lambda call to avoid spreading `init()` out of the namespace:

```
namespace Blocks {
    enum ID {
        AIR = 0,
        DIRT = 1,
    };
    auto DATA = [] {
        std::vector<BlockData> DATA(2);
        DATA[Blocks::ID::AIR] = BlockData{32};
        DATA[Blocks::ID::DIRT] = BlockData{6};
        return DATA;
    }();
}
```

Comment: Problem I have with this is that it is hard-coding the size of the vector, which is an "opportunity" to forget to change the size if additional enumerated values are added (or some are added and later removed).   To mitigate that, I'd consider changing the `enum` to something like `enum ID {AIR = 0, DIRT = 1, NUM_IDS};` and changing the vector definition in the lambda to `std::vector<BlockData> DATA(Blocks::ID::NUM_IDS);`

Comment: @Peter Yeah, you're right to mention that. Am i right in understanding that NUM_IDS will be just `DIRT + 1`, but not total real size of enum? This makes it more reliable, but if there are "holes" in enumerator, it still will cause problems. Do you know of any ways to get real size of enum? Or that requires different approach to handle that? Because advantage of enum in my case was that it's resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Rostys   In the example given, `NUM_IDS` will be `DIRT + 1`.   More generally, an enumerated name that isn't given an explicit value is equal to value associated with the previous name plus 1 (unless it is the first, in which case, it gets a value 0).   So, if you something like `enum thing {NAME1 = 15, NAME2 = 5, NAME3};` then `NAME3` will have a value 6.   But declaring the enumeration in increasing order means the last (even if not given a value) will be equal to the maximum.